# WSO2 IS 5.5 - Advanced Authentication Configuration not saving

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to setup multi-factor authentication in WSO2 Identity Server 5.5. As per instructions, I have installed and configured totp as a possible second factor. Within my service provider, I'm attempting to add multiple steps to the Advanced Authentication Configuration screen under the Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration section, and modifications are not saving when pressing Update.

I understand that some of the UI operations do not always operate as expected, so I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this or perhaps could specify where the service provider config files are located so I can make these changes manually?

For my use case, I just want to have basic as the first step/factor and then totp as the second. Nothing seems to save on this screen.

Thanks.

[screenshot-advanced configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aDKn.png)

Comment: After selecting the authenticator you need to press "Add authenticator" button?. Did you press it?

Comment: Thanks, this worked